# Syntax Error: Unterminated Quoted String when using Intel's PIN tool on controlCARD executable

Tags: trace, intel-pin, code-composer

I am having some issues with Intel's PIN tool when obtaining the dynamic trace from a program's executable. I have previously used this tool on other programs successfully.

I wrote some code for TI's Piccolo TMS320F28035 Isolated controlCARD. I was successfully able to build it and it runs in Code Composer. I took the .out file, and I want to obtain the dynamic trace for it. I tried using Intel's PIN tool and it runs for about 10 seconds before exiting with a **"Syntax Error: Unterminated Quoted String"** error. I understand this error means there is a missing quotation mark somewhere, but I am not sure how to address this error considering it built with no problems on Code Composer.

Any suggestions or thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you mention how you execute TI microcontroller code with Intel pin tool.

Comment: I basically used Code Composer to write and build the code. Once it built with no errors, I   programmed the board and made sure the code worked as intended. I then took the ".out" file, which is the executable, and I used TI's dis2000 tool to attain the static disassembly. For the dynamic trace, I used Intel's PIN tool, which I have tested on other programs, so I know the tool works. To execute it, it's just " /path_to_pintool-executable  -t   /path_to_itrace.so  --  /path_to_excutable-to-be-disassembled"

Comment: What is your objective - to execute the "X.out" file  and collect its trace or get the trace of tool (dis2000) while it is disassembling your X.out file?

Comment: PIN is an Intel tool, capable of collecting trace of an executable that run on Intel platform. It cannot execute a TI micro-controller executable and collect its trace.

Comment: Yes, the dis2000 tool attains the static disassembly. I was desiring the full runtime trace. I was afraid that the Intel PIN tool wouldn't work because of the different platforms. Thanks!